# Ng-grid and sorting array data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I'm using ng-grid where the data source is an array of arrays like so

```
 $scope.myData = [
      ["Moroni", "M"],
      ["Tiancum", "T"],
      ["Jacob", "J"],
      ["Nephi", "N"],
      ["Enos", "E"]
    ]
```

The full example can be found on this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/LK6RNzagHEEoHmMKB1Ri?p=preview

The actual problem is that the data does not sort while the user clicks the column headers. Is this the expected behaviour? Is there a way to get the data to sort when you click a column?

Thanks

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Comment: Errm, what answer? And did it work? I don't get it. Is this still a question?

Comment: there was a response that has since been deleted. And yes this is still a question.